# $(this) and $(element) in jQuery's each method

Tags: jquery, loops, element, this, each

Is there a speed difference between `$(this)` and `$(elem)` (second parameter) in jQuery's `.each()` "loop"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; `this` and `elem` both refer to a raw DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

The `elem` parameter is also set to `this`, so no, there's no difference.